# Create separate options menu in every fragment

Tags: java, android, menu, fragment

i have three fragments with action bar. i would like to have separate option menu.
Suppose,
**Fragment A**, **Fragment B**, **Fragment C**
i want different option items in each fragment.

What would be the better coding approach, for doing this ?
I use java as the coding language

Answer (score 0):

There should be a method like getMenuOptions() in activity. As soon as you load the fragment, call this method. Method should be called from every fragment(That means fragment should call activity method, There are many approaches and can easily be found to call activity method in fragment). That method will be responsible to update the menu option and other things.

Comment: could not find that method

Answer (score 0):

Override `onCreateOptionsMenu` in each fragment to inflate different menus.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, parent, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // <-- Important
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: In this process, we need to create xml of every menu right!

Comment: Yes, that is what you wanted, no? To have different menu options for each fragment.